# Regex for match beginning with 2 letters and ending with 3 letters

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, jscript

Example input:

```js
'Please find the ref AB45676785567XYZ. which is used to identify reference number'
```

Example output:

```js
'AB45676785567XYZ'
```

I need a `RegExp` to return the match exactly matching my requirements; i.e. the substring where the first 2 and last 3 characters are letters.

The first 2 and last 3 letters are unknown.

I've tried this `RegExp`:

```js
[a-zA-Z]{2}[^\s]*?[a-zA-Z]{3}
```

But it is not matching as intended.

Comment: If you're not sure, or having trouble working out what the regex should be, try using [regex tester](https://regex101.com)  This shows you the result and steps through the expression bit by bit to show how the match is being performed.  There are, of course, other sites available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `RegExp` matches the following words marked with code blocks:

> `Please` find the ref `AB45676785567XYZ`. which is used to `identify` `reference` `number`

This is because your `RegExp`, `[a-zA-Z]{2}[^\s]*?[a-zA-Z]{3}`, is asking for:

- `[a-zA-Z]{2}` Begins with 2 letters (either case)
- `[^\s]*?` Contains anything that isn't a whitespace
- `[a-zA-Z]{3}` Ends with 3 letters (either case)

In your current example, restricting the letters to uppercase only would match only the match you seek:

```
[A-Z]{2}[^\s]+[A-Z]{3}
```

Alternatively, requiring numbers between the 2 beginning and 3 ending letters would also produce the match you want:

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}\d+[a-zA-Z]{3}
```

Comment: It would match even `AB45676785567XYZ-some` in `AB45676785567XYZ-some more text`

Comment: Suppose my text will be "Please find the ref AB45676abc85567XYZ. which is used to identify reference number". Can you please provide Regex for this ?

Comment: `[A-Z]{2}[^\s]+[A-Z]{3}`

Answer (score 1):

What is really important here, is word boundaries `\b`, try: `\b[a-zA-Z]{2}\w+[a-zA-Z]{3}\b`

Explanation:

`\b` - word boundary

`[a-zA-Z]{2}` - match any letter, 2 times

`\w+` - match one or more word characters

`[a-zA-Z]{3}` - match any letter, 3 times

`\b` - word boundary

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LYWK9H/1)

**CAUTION** your requirements are amibgious, as any word consisting of 5 or more letters would match the pattern

Answer (score 0):

Start with 2 letters :

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}
```

Digits in the middle :

```
\d+
```

Finish with 3 letters :

```
[a-zA-Z]{3}
```

Full Regex :

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}\d+[a-zA-Z]{3}
```

If the middle text is Alpha-Numeric, you can use this :

```
[A-Z]{2}[^\s]+[A-Z]{3}
```

Comment: What if string will consist of letters only? It would still match OP requirements.

Comment: Suppose my text will be "Please find the ref AB45676abc85567XYZ. which is used to identify reference number". Can you please provide Regex for this ?